# Need assistance with dictionaries, csv files, and lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Alright, so I need a code that will take a csv file and reads the values in it (so far I've gotten that part down).

What I'm having trouble with is creating a list with those values, and ordering them in order of less re-occurring to most re-occurring. There can be no duplicate values either.

Here's what I have:

```
import csv
B = []
K = []
def readandprocess(name):
with open(name, newline='') as csvf:
    freader = csv.reader(csvf,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
    datasg = {}
    artists = []



    for row in freader:
        artist = row[2]
        B.append(artist)


    for artist in B:
            c = B.count(artist)
            K.append(artist + str(c))


    list(set(K))
    print(K)

    #for row in freader:
        #artist = row[2]
        ###song = row[1]
        #if artist == 'Rolling Stones':
        #    print('Rolling Stones title: ',row[1])
        #if artist not in datasg:
        #   datasg[artist] = [song]
       #else:
            #datasg[artist].append(song)
    #for artist in datasg:
        #print(artist, datasg[artist])
    print( '--------------------------------------')
    info = datasg.items()
   # tosort = [(len(t[1]),t[0]) for t in info]
   # info = sorted(tosort)
   # print(info[-30:])
   # print(info)

print(len(datasg))   # currently 0, populate at will #Number of keys in dictionary
return datasg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    datasg = readandprocess('data/top1000.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Once you have all the items you need in a list, you can use a Counter, and then call [`most_common(n)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to get the `n` most common elements.

Comment: Seems usable, but my python doesn't recognize counter as a function, what do I need to import to fix this?

Comment: `from collections import Counter`

Comment: Glad it worked. If this answers your question, can you please accept the answer?